# Set textblock text which is inside user control multiline

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, textblock

I have a user control which contains a textblock with word wrap.

```
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock MaxWidth="500"
               Margin="2"
               Text="{Binding HintHeader}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />

    <TextBlock MaxWidth="500"
               Margin="2"
               Text="{Binding HintBody}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Hintbody is dependency property of user control. I can use the control in other place fine as:

```
<cntrls:HintButton x:Name="hint"
                   Width="24"
                   Height="24"
                   Margin="85,68,0,0"
                   HintHeader="This is an header"
                   HintBody="This is an hint"/>
```

Everything works fine. But I want set a multiline text to the textblock (HintBody).
Setting Hintbody property using "\r\n" from code behind works fine. But I want to set the same from XAML. Something like.

```
<cntrls:HintButton x:Name="hint"
                       Width="24"
                       Height="24"
                       Margin="85,68,0,0"
                       HintHeader="Hint Header" >
      <cntrls:HintButton.HintBody>
        This is a multiline hint body.
        <LineBreak />
        This is a multiline hint body.
      </cntrls:HintButton.HintBody>      
    </cntrls:HintButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a ContentPresenter instead of TextBlock inside the user control for the HintBody. That would give you greater flexibility in what you can do now and in the future.

```
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock MaxWidth="500"
           Margin="2"
           Text="{Binding HintHeader}"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" />

    <ContentPresenter MaxWidth="500"
           Margin="2"
           Text="{Binding HintBody}"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

You'd need to change the type of HintBody property to be object. Then you could do:

```
<cntrls:HintButton x:Name="hint"
                   Width="24"
                   Height="24"
                   Margin="85,68,0,0"
                   HintHeader="Hint Header" >
  <cntrls:HintButton.HintBody>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="This is a line."/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="This is another line"/>
    </TextBlock>     
  </cntrls:HintButton.HintBody> 
</cntrls:HintButton>
```